# Help me clarify these probability theory problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given Joint Density Function

$$f(x,y)= 24xy,\ 0<x<1,\ 0<y<1\ \text{and}\ x+y<1$$

Is $$P(x+y<1/2)= \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}-y}f(x,y)dxdy?$$

Is $P(x+y>1/2)$= what is the correct integration?

To the two questions above why so? How can I defend it.

Thanks by the ways

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to visualize this problem is via a graph. Consider the following:

[image]

The dark black line is $y=0.5-x$ or $x=0.5-y$

You want to find the **volume** under the graph. I would provide both the solutions for you.

\begin{align}
\text{Pr} \begin{pmatrix}x+y<\frac 12\end{pmatrix}
&=\int_{y=0}^{y=0.5}\int_{x=0}^{x=0.5-y}24xy \,dx\,dy\\
&=\int_{y=0}^{y=0.5} \begin{bmatrix}12x^2y \end{bmatrix}_{x=0}^{x=0.5-y} \,dy\\
&=\int_{y=0}^{y=0.5} 12y(0.5-y)^2 \,dy\\&=0.0625
\end{align}

The trick here is to stand at the $x$-axis and look up. On your left is $x=0$ and on your right is $x=0.5-y$. Hence these are the limits. You are integrating from $y=0$ to $y=0.5$ because that is the valid range which the triangle lies.

or

\begin{align}
\text{Pr} \begin{pmatrix}x+y<\frac 12\end{pmatrix}
&=\int_{x=0}^{x=0.5}\int_{y=0}^{y=0.5-x}24xy \,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_{x=0}^{x=0.5} \begin{bmatrix}12xy^2 \end{bmatrix}_{y=0}^{y=0.5-x} \,dx\\
&=\int_{x=0}^{x=0.5} 12x(0.5-x)^2  \,dx\\
&=0.0625
\end{align}

Similarly, stand next to the $y$-axis and look forward. On the top is $y=0.5-x$ and you stand on $y=0$. Hence these are the limits. You are integrating from $x=0$ to $x=0.5$ because that is the valid range which the triangle lies.

Both results will be equal.

For your second question, consider that $\text{Pr} \begin{pmatrix}x+y>\frac 12\end{pmatrix} = 1-\text{Pr} \begin{pmatrix}x+y<\frac 12\end{pmatrix}$. Simply take $1-$ the above result and you get it. You can do the above again but I think this method suffices due to the earlier result you found. If you are doing this question in exams and you are pressed for time, find these methods to make your calculations shorter.

In fact, if you do the integration under the line $y=1-x$, you should be able to get $1$. However, to emphasize the illustration, I shall perform the integration for you.

\begin{align}
\text{Pr} \begin{pmatrix}x+y>\frac 12\end{pmatrix}
&=\int_{x=0}^{x=0.5}\int_{y=0.5-x}^{y=1-x}24xy \,dy\,dx + \int_{x=0.5}^{x=1}\int_{y=0}^{y=1-x}24xy \,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_{x=0}^{x=0.5} \begin{bmatrix}12xy^2 \end{bmatrix}_{y=0.5-x}^{y=1-x} \,dx+
\int_{x=0.5}^{x=1} \begin{bmatrix}12xy^2 \end{bmatrix}_{y=0}^{y=1-x} \,dx\\
&=\int_{x=0}^{x=0.5} 12x(\frac 34 - x)  \,dx + \int_{x=0.5}^{x=1} 12x(1-x)^2  \,dx\\
&=0.625 + 0.3125 = 0.9375
\end{align}

And, as you can see, $$\text{Pr} \begin{pmatrix}x+y<\frac 12\end{pmatrix} + \text{Pr} \begin{pmatrix}x+y>\frac 12\end{pmatrix} = 1$$

Comment: What is the Pr (x+y>1/2) would be?

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\text{Pr}(x>\frac 12 , y> \frac 12)$?

Comment: Pr (x+y>1/2) IDK it makes me go insane

Comment: I think you have a typo in the second part of your question. First, it should be $X$ not $x$ and the equals sign should be replaced by an addition sign. Clarify this and I will look at it again.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry. Lol on my mistake. Yeah it is Pr(x+y>1/2). How should I integrate?

Comment: Added for your second part.

Comment: Hello @TRIGO, I have performed the integration for the second part for completeness sake. Take a look. As shown, the values indeed add up to $1$.

Comment: Thanks, it helps during the test.